# Why Url.Action doesn't include action name when there are more parameters

Tags: .net-core, routes

Hi I have configured default route:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Now when I call:
`Url.Action("GroupView", new {id = "(groupId)", categoryId = "(categoryId)"})`

I expect that URL to be returned:
`/Document/GroupView/(groupId)?categoryId=(categoryId)`
(as my controller is DocumentController)

Insetad of this, I am getting:
`/(groupId)?categoryId=(categoryId)`

Why is that?

I don't have any attributes on controller, but `[Authorize]`

My action method though looks like that:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GroupCategoryView(Guid id, Guid? categoryId)
{
   CategoryModel model = new CategoryModel();
   //some more code removed for clarity
   return PartialView(model);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have action with name `GroupCategoryView` but refer as `GroupView`
If you want to go this way you should have your get attribute as  `[HttpGet("/GroupView/{id}")]`

And BTW controller must have attribute `[Route("Document")]`

Detailed explanation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ar)

You hitting the default controller because your action found nowhere.

Comment: I don't agree. Firstly because it should use current controller name when no controller name is specified, secondly, when I add controller name to Action method, the result is the same. What's more, it works when I don't have any parameters, so Url.Action("ActionName") would return proper URL.

Comment: Did you add attributes to the actions? If no Map controllers won't work

Comment: Yes I did: [HttpGet("{id}")]

Comment: You should specify not only get: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#ar Can you please show the action method with the controller signature

Comment: Look at my modified post

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading I got to a point that Http attributes should not rather be used with WebApplication. WebApplication urls are Routed based. So one have to configure Routes. Http attributes are for WebAPI projects. So after deleting this attribute from controller method, everything started working.